# Append values to list within a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list

As simple as this sounds I cannot figure it out... Here's what I want to do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
{'first names' :  ['trey', 'tagg']},
{'first names' :  ['teague', 'tanner']},
]
)
```

df

|  | first names |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [trey, tagg] |
| 1 | ['teague', 'tanner'] |

I would like to do something such as `df['first names'].append('joe')` and get the result..

|  | first names |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [trey, tagg, joe] |
| 1 | ['teague', 'tanner', joe] |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["first names"].apply(lambda lst: lst.append("joe"))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
             first names
0      [trey, tagg, joe]
1  [teague, tanner, joe]
```

Comment: Thanks! I swapped out `apply()` with `map()` and that works too

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
for val in df['first names']:
    val.append('jeo')
print(df)
```

output

```
             first names
0      [trey, tagg, jeo]
1  [teague, tanner, jeo]
```